# How to reliably get pid of twistd spawned process?

Tags: python, linux, twisted, pid, twistd

I have a Python program that uses [psutil](http://code.google.com/p/psutil/) to run some various `twistd ...` commands. `twistd` spawns and daemonizes a process and writes a `foo.pid` from which I can read the pid.

It also sets up so that this pid-file is cleaned up when the process terminates, which means that it is possible for the spawned process to finish so fast that I cannot read the pid.

`twistd` does return with an error code if it cannot write a pid file, so I can assume that no pid file and no twisted error code means the process was spawned successfully and very quickly terminated, but this whole process seems so flaky. Not to mention having to wait for the pid file to be filled with content while also handling the possibility that it is filled but removed again in one go.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a better way (or if there is, it's very difficult or impossible to know what it is, since you haven't described the general problem you're solving, you've just described a problem you have with a solution you've already selected).

There's an [open feature request](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/ticket/823) for making `twistd` more amenable to this sort of use, though.  If you help resolve it, then you'll be able to do this how you want.

Comment: My "already selected" solution is just my best attempt. It cannot, for example separate between the utmost bizarre behavior of `twistd` when a command line is wrong and it returns with an exit code of zero and a program that simply terminates very fast, which is why I asked the question.

Comment: Sorry, I guess my point wasn't clear enough.  Why are you launching a daemonizing twistd child process and then attempting to learn its pid at all?  What's the overall goal?

Comment: The general problem is to launch and monitor a few twistd services, killing them when necessary, as well as reporting stuff such as memory and cpu usage.

Comment: Then the solution is to use something like daemontools, or at least implement something that works roughly like daemontools - which means *not* daemonizing twistd.  Pass --nodaemon.  Now you know the process's pid, because there's no forking, and you know when it needs to be restarted, because it only exits when it is done.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what part you're using psutil for, but just calling [spawnProcess](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/12.1.0/api/twisted.internet.interfaces.IReactorProcess.html#spawnProcess) from Twisted will fire with an `IReactorProcess` that knows its pid.

If it's `twistd` you're calling out to, there's definitely a way to do what you'd be doing within the same process too if you'd like.

Comment: The question very explicitly specifies `twistd` being used. I am not asking how to create processes, but how to get the pid of a process started with command line `twistd`. I know I can run `twistd` with `-n` to not daemonize it in which case I can use the pid of the process I spawn myself with psutil, although I am unsure about the implications.

Comment: Thanks, I see it specifies `twistd`, that doesn't mean it's clear to me where you're using it :). Your question says you're using `psutil` "to run some various twistd ... commands". That sounds like you're spawning new processes. (And no, `-n` isn't relevant)

Comment: Actually, `-n` makes it so that the `twistd` process being spawned using `Popen` is the process that I am interested in, i.e. the pid of my `Popen` spawned process is the same as the pid in the .pid file.